# spring utility project - java.io.FileNotFoundException on Ubuntu

Tags: java, spring, filenotfoundexception

I'm newly at Spring.
I tried to write easy project and stack with weird exception [FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/filenotfoundexception/info).

To my mind it is some problem with loading `app-context.xml`. But I sure that set correct absolute path.

Any suggestions?

**Main code:**

package com.prospring.ch2;

```
public class HelloWorldSpringDI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "/home/nazar_art/workspace/ch2/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml");
        MessageRenderer mr = ctx.getBean("renderer", MessageRenderer.class);
        mr.render();
    }
}
```

Here **content of** `app-context.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="provider" class="com.prospring.ch2.HelloWorldMessageProvider" />
    <bean id="rendere" class="com.prospring.ch2.StandartOutMessageRenderer" 
        p:messageProvider-ref="provider" />

    <!--<description>Example configuration to get you started.</description --> 
    <!-- context:component-scan base-package="com.prospring.ch2" />  -->
</beans>
```

snippet of **console message**:

```
14:24:06,360  INFO t.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext: 456 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@3f62e847: startup date [Wed Nov 13 14:24:06 EET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
14:24:06,509  INFO eans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: 315 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [home/nazar_art/workspace/ch2/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [home/nazar_art/workspace/ch2/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [home/nazar_art/workspace/ch2/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I checked path to `app-context.xml` **from terminal** all looks ok:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~/workspace/ch2/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring$ pwd
/home/nazar_art/workspace/ch2/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring
nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~/workspace/ch2/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring$ ls -lg
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nazar_art 867 Nov 13 14:25 app-context.xml
```

Here is looking of my struckture:

[image: spring project struckture]

- **How to solve this trouble?**

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html

Comment: Have you tried to debug it and see exactly when and where the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the class path application context loader [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html) and passing an absolute path to it.

You need to use [FileSystemXmlApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html)

If you want to use [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html) then you have to make sure your `app-context.xml` is in the class path of your application and pass the appropriate resource name, which is different from the absolute path on a filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
            "/home/nazar_art/workspace/ch2/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/app-context.xml");
    ...
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "META-INF/spring/app-context.xml");
  ...
}
```

[FileSystemXmlApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html)

[ClassPathXmlApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html)

Comment: I used this `"META-INF/spring/app-context.xml"`